# Car doesn't start for 1 hr

Tags: engine, starting, dodge

My 1997 Dodge grand Caravan will run fine for about 2 to 3 weeks, then all of a sudden when I turn it off it doesn't want to start back up: all the lights work just fine and I got full power, but it just won't turn over. If I let it sit for about an hour then it will start and works fine. What could that be?

It has 236,000 miles, The motor and transmission have both been rebuilt, Rebuilt motor has about 85,000 miles.

Comment: Could you add specific details about you car? Make, Model, miles, et cetera.

Comment: It's a 1997 Dodge grand Caravan It has 236,000 miles, The motor and transmission have both been rebuilt, Rebuilt motor has about 85,000 miles

Comment: You could edit your post, you know. ;) Anyhow, does it happen in the rain, humid weather, going through puddle, etc.? If it turns over but does not start, it could be plug wires, and if it does not turn over (starter is not engaging), connections should be checked and cleaned, and insulation on the cables should be checked for damage. Most electrical problems are caused by faulty connections.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem.Does starter motor click when trying to start?Solenoid could be on the
way out as in my case.Go to source;battery could be sulphated.Any garage or batt. supplier will test it (usually free).Check & clean all leads to batt. & s/motor ensuring
they're all tight and free of corrosion.It's often the simple things